# Encrypt/Decrypt between Postgres and Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, encryption, aes

**Problem**: We have to encrypt a certain column on a certain table (Postgres). It has to be decryptable in SQL queries *and* in our nodejs/sequelize application layer. The encryption can happen in either layer, but it must be decodable from either.

The issue I'm running into (and I'm sure it's user error) is that if I encrypt in the db I can only decrypt in the db, and the same for node.

I've tried using `PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT` and `ENCRYPT` in postgres and `crypto` and `crypto-js/aes` in node. I've gotten it to the point where it's decrypting without an error, but returns gibberish.

**A few things I've tried so far** (test key is `thirtytwocharsthirtytwocharsplus`):

```
set() {
  this.setDataValue('field', seq.cast(seq.fn('PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT', val, 
  config.AES_KEY), 'text'))
}
```

This properly writes the field such that PGP_SYM_DECRYPT will decrypt it, but there's (apparently?) no way to tell Sequelize to wrap the field name with a function call so it's a lot of extra js that I feel is avoidable

```
const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', config.AES_KEY)
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
return decipher.update(new Buffer(this.getDataValue('field', 'binary'), 'binary', 'ascii')) + decipher.final('ascii')
```

This will decode the field but returns gibberish (`�Mq��8Ya�b`) instead of the value (`test`)

```
aes.encrypt('test', config.AES_KEY)
aes.decrypt(field, config.AES_KEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

This encrypts fine, decrypts fine, but Postgres errors when trying to decrypt (using either `PGP_SYM_DECRYPT` or `DECRYPT`). Casting the resulting field to `::TEXT` and pasting it into an online AES Decrypter returns the expected value.

I *really* want to avoid having to add a bunch of boilerplate to our node repositories/queries, and I really feel like this should work. Using the same crypto algorithm should yield the same results

Any nudge or pointer would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide more information on the encryption used at the database level?  You are using the same algorithm, sure, but theres a lot more to encryption than just the algorithm.  Block Mode?  Padding?  IV?

Comment: This is where the "user error" probably comes in. I'm just using the default behaviour for each function (`PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(-, -, "cipher-algo=aes256")`, `ENCRYPT(-, -, 'aes')`, and `aes.encrypt(-, -)`

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure that pgcrypto `encrypt()` isn't going to work for me and I'm going to need to use `PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT()`

Answer (score 3):

Postgres has rather unclear documentation about the raw encryption functions. After a few tries and failures, I managed to replicate most of logic logic in nodejs.

Here is the program I used.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const iv = Buffer.alloc(16); // zeroed-out iv

function encrypt(plainText, algorithm, key) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'base64');
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return encrypted;
}

function decrypt(encrypted, algorithm, key) {
  const decrypt = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let text = decrypt.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
  text += decrypt.final('utf8')
  return text;
}

const originalText = "hello world";
const userKey = 'abcd'
const algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc';

const paddedKey = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(userKey), Buffer.alloc(12)]); // make it 128 bits key

const hw = encrypt(originalText, algorithm, paddedKey);
console.log("original", originalText);
console.log("encrypted:", hw);
console.log("decoded: ", decrypt(hw, algorithm, paddedKey).toString());
```

Also here is a list of things not documented for the raw functions of postgres:

- the key will be auto padded to match one of the 3 lengths: 128 bits, 192 bits, 256 bits
- algorithm is automatically upgraded, when key length exceeds the limit. e.g. if key exceeds 128bits, `aes-192-cbc` will be used to encrypt
- if key exceeds 256 bits, it will be truncated to 256 bits.

It would be easier to replicate it in application language (either Javascript or Java), if Postgres has proper documentation of these functions.

Comment: Hi, i have a quick question. i have successfully encrypted my users mobile number when storing in db, but now in my registration flow i want to compare the new users entered mobile number with the one in my database, How do i do that?

Comment: You can try to read the mobile number (plaintext) from a new registration, then encrypt it the same way and compare it with the ones already stored in db.

Comment: You're my friggen hero, though the lede was buried for me. I spent half the night trying to figure out why I was seeing data errors when trying to store results of a crypto cipher when I realized I should've set the output encoding to base64.

Answer (score 1):

I spent so much time getting this to work, I figured I'd post my full typescript solution here and hopefully save others some time.

These functions encrypt and then decrypt strings that can be stored in postgres `text` or `varchar` fields.

```
import * as openpgp from 'openpgp';

const key = '<your-encryption-key>';
const hexPrefix = `${String.fromCharCode(92)}x`; // postgres needs a \x prefix

export async function encrypt(plainText: string): Promise<string> {
  const message = await openpgp.createMessage({ text: plainText });
  const encryptedBinary = await openpgp.encrypt({
    message,
    passwords: key,
    format: 'binary',
    config: {
      preferredSymmetricAlgorithm: openpgp.enums.symmetric.aes256,
      preferredCompressionAlgorithm: openpgp.enums.compression.zip,
    },
  });
  const encryptedHex = Buffer.from(encryptedBinary).toString('hex');
  return `${hexPrefix}${encryptedHex}`;
}

export async function decrypt(hexFromPostgres: string): Promise<string> {
  const trimmedHex = hexFromPostgres.slice(hexPrefix.length); // remove `\x' from beginning
  const binaryToDecrypt = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(trimmedHex, 'hex'));
  const decrypted = await openpgp.decrypt({
    message: await openpgp.readMessage({ binaryMessage: binaryToDecrypt }),
    passwords: key,
  });
  return decrypted.data;
}
```

The strings can be encrypted and decrypted in postgres with

```
pgp_sym_encrypt('message to encrypt', '<your-encryption-key', 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')

pgp_sym_decrypt(<column-name>::bytea, '<your-encryption-key')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working, hopefully properly

What I did was:

Encrypting with `crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', new Buffer(config.AES_KEY), iv)` in node, `encrypt_iv` in pgsql and storing as `hex` in the db, and decrypting with `crypto.createDecipheriv`/`decrypt_iv` into `text`/`utf8`

I don't know what part I was missing, but between specifying `aes256`, using the `iv` methods, and flipping juggling hex/text it seems to be working.

Comment: Ensure you aren't using the same IV for each encryption operation.  Doing that is a security vulnerability.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example?

Answer (score -1):

For me, It worked with a similar approach suggested by KLPainter above
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75861980/13757228

but a little bit of correction it goes as follows:

```js
const key = "<your-encryption-key>";
const decrypt = async (hexFromPostgres) => {
  try {
      // issue was here it removes 3/4 chars instead of just 2 chars so I manually removed the '\x' and defined it as trimmedHex
      // const trimmedHex = hexFromPostgres.slice(hexPrefix.length);
      // remove `\x' from beginning

    // hexFromPostgres = "\x92eb5bf752d8dthisiissample";
    const trimmedHex = "92eb5bf752d8dthisiissample";

    const binaryToDecrypt = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(trimmedHex, "hex"));
    const encryptedMsg = await openpgp.readMessage({
      binaryMessage: binaryToDecrypt,
    });

    const decrypted = await openpgp.decrypt({
      message: encryptedMsg,
      passwords: [key], // here added key in array
      format: "binary", // defined the format as binary
    });

    const string = new TextDecoder().decode(decrypted.data);
    console.log(string);
    return string;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("---error while decryption: ", e);
  }
  return `test`;
};
```

Hope this is helpful