# PostgreSQL encryption to Node.js decryption

Tags: node.js, postgresql, cryptojs, pgcrypto

In Postgres, I am using:

```
encrypt('text', 'mykey', 'aes')
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/pgcrypto.html - F.20.4. Raw encryption functions

I assume this is done using the defaults of AES-128 algorithm, CBC mode.

It appears to be stored as BINARY (16 bytes) in the database and comes back as a base64? encoded string when I request the column on the server with my ORM.

In Node.js, assuming I have 'mykey', how do I convert this value back to its plaintext using `crypto` or `crypto-js` libraries?

Comment: By using an AES-128, CBC algorithm in Node (give or take some base64 encoding/decoding)?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't offer a function names "encrypt" taking two arguments.  Where did you find it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but I was unable to get it to work with the libraries. I could use a basic, working example showing the decryption.

Comment: @jjanes Sorry, updated and clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use PostgreSQL's Pgp_sym_encrypt() instead, and then use it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp to decode?  PostgreSQL's raw encryption functions are not really suitable for compatible use with external systems (and really, not suitable for use at all)

Comment: true. pgp_sym_encrypt() is preferred. PostgreSQL's raw encryption functions lack of clear documentation. I left the details in my comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63095117/709065, hopefully it helps save time for other folks.